# Akka.net Executing long-running actions inside an actor’s Receive method

Tags: c#, akka, actor, distributed-system, akka.net

I'm **newbie in Akka.net framework**

want to execute job long-running operation inside Receive method then my actors will be unable to process any messages Plus how to cancel (terminate) running job , including system messages, until that operation finishes. And if it’s possible that the operation will never finish, it’s possible to deadlock my actor.

**Expected behavior:** once click on cancel button should should stop current execution `for loop` Plus ui must be reliable to start new job as current code run job in **Task with cancellation**

**Current Result behavior:** it won't cancel current execution `for loop` and cannot start new job while a current job executing

here **JobActor.cs**

```
public class JobActor : ReceiveActor, IWithUnboundedStash
    {
        private readonly IActorRef supervisor_;
        private readonly List<KeyValuePair<int, IJob>> jobs_;
        private IJobManagerFactory _jobFactory;
        private Stopwatch _timer;
        private ILoggingAdapter _loggingAdapter;
        private Task _runningTask;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancel;

        public IStash Stash { get; set; }


        public JobActor(IActorRef supervisor, IJobManagerFactory jobFactory)
        {
            _jobFactory = jobFactory;
            _cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
            supervisor_ = supervisor;
            jobs_ = new List<KeyValuePair<int, IJob>>();
            _loggingAdapter = Context.GetLogger();
            _timer = new Stopwatch();
            Ready();

        }

        private void Ready()
        {
            Receive<Run>(run =>
            {
                var self = Self; // closure
                _runningTask = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // ... work
                    var job = _jobFactory.CreateJob(run);
                    job.Started += () =>
                    {
                        _timer.Start();
                        supervisor_.Tell(new Started(job.Id));
                        _loggingAdapter.Info($"Job {job.Id} started.");
                    };
                    job.Progressed += (percent) =>
                    {
                        supervisor_.Tell(new Progress(job.Id, Convert.ToInt32(_timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)));
                        _loggingAdapter.Debug($"Job {job.Id} is now {percent}% complete.");
                    };

                    job.StatusChanged += status =>
                    {
                        supervisor_.Tell(new StatusChanged(job.Id, job.Status));
                        _loggingAdapter.Info($"Job {job.Id} has changed status to {job.Status}.");
                    };
                    job.Finished += () =>
                    {
                        _timer.Stop();
                        supervisor_.Tell(new Progress(job.Id, Convert.ToInt32(_timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)));
                        supervisor_.Tell(new Finished(job.Id));
                        _loggingAdapter.Info($"Job {job.Id} finished.");
                    };
                    var jobStore = new KeyValuePair<int, IJob>(job.Id, job);
                    _loggingAdapter.Info($"Job {job.Id} starting.");
                    jobs_.Add(jobStore);
                    job.Run();


                }, _cancel.Token).ContinueWith(x =>
                {
                    if (x.IsCanceled || x.IsFaulted)
                        new Cancel(run.Id);
                    new Finished(run.Id);
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
                .PipeTo(self);

                // switch behavior
                Become(Working);
            });

            Receive<Cancel>(cancel =>
            {
                _timer.Stop();
                IJob job = jobs_.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == cancel.Id).Value;
                _loggingAdapter.Info($"Canceling job {cancel.Id}.");
                job?.Cancel();

            });
            
        }

        private void Working()
        {
            Receive<Cancel>(cancel =>
            {
                _cancel.Cancel(); // cancel work
                BecomeReady();
            });
            Receive<Failed>(f => BecomeReady());
            Receive<Finished>(f => BecomeReady());
            ReceiveAny(o => Stash.Stash());
        }

        private void BecomeReady()
        {
            _cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Stash.UnstashAll();
            Become(Ready);
        }
    }
```

here **JobManager.cs**

```
 public class JobManager : IJob
    {
        private readonly Timer timer_;
        private int percentCounter_;
        private JobStatus status_;
        public JobManager(Run run)
        {
            Id = run.Id;

            Status = JobStatus.New;
            timer_ = new Timer(1000) { AutoReset = true };
            timer_.Elapsed += (sender, eventargs) =>
            {
                Progressed?.Invoke(percentCounter_);
            };
        }


        public int Id { get; }

        public JobStatus Status
        {
            get { return status_; }
            set
            {
                status_ = value;
                StatusChanged?.Invoke(status_);
            }
        }

        public event Action<int> Progressed;
        public event Action Finished;
        public event Action Started;

        public event Action<JobStatus> StatusChanged;
        public void Run()
        {
            timer_.Start();
            Started?.Invoke();
            Status = JobStatus.Running;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
            timer_.Stop();
            timer_.Close();
            Status = JobStatus.Canceled;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `work` loop (it's pseudo-code in this sample) evaluate the `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` property? If not, then the `Task` won't actually be cancelled even though you passed a `CancellationToken` into it. Your user-defined code should close over the `CancellationToken` and check, on each iteration of the loop, whether or not cancellation has been requested.